# Unable to start mysql with docker on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Am Unable to start mysql with docker on Ubuntu. Get the following error:

> db_1_cc1214d5085c | ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check
>   config db_1_cc1214d5085c | command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"
>   db_1_cc1214d5085c | db_1_cc1214d5085c | mysqld: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot stat shared object:
>   Permission denied

Content of docker compose file:

```
version: '2.4'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
#   restart: always
    volumes:
     - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Docker details:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:48:57 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Server: Docker Engine - Community

```
Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       4d60db4
  Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:16:44 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Also worth noting is that there is a non dockerized versionof MySQL installed and running on this server. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check permissions on `./data/db` folder on your host?

Comment: Check this thread https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7512

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619823/mysql-cannot-be-started-in-mgt-development-environment is a similar issue resolved with AppArmor config, though the one answer there isn't a good one.

Comment: Konrad i already checked the thread and David i removed aparmor. I will check the permissions on the folder today and update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start mysql service you'll need to have something like this in your docker-compose file

```
version: '3'    
services:
 <service-name>:
   image: mysql:5.7
   container_name: <container-name>
   ports:
     - "<host-port>:<container-port>"
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<root-password>
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=<database-name>
   volumes:
     - <host-dir>:/var/lib/mysql
   networks: ['stack']
networks:
  stack:
    driver: bridge
```

Make sure that `<host-dir>` you have permission with the current user executing the `docker-compose up` command.

The `networks` is used if you have multiple services that want to connect to the database they all should consume the same `network` which is `stack` in this example

looks like a permission problem on your host.

Comment: The `networks:` sections are unnecessary; Docker Compose will create a default bridge-type network for you and connect containers to it automatically.  Explicitly specifying `container_name:` is also unnecessary and makes it harder to reuse the same file.  If you strip those two things out, this is basically identical to the YAML file in the original question.

Comment: Am accepting this as the answer because my app was defined to work on a docker network. Hence it became necessary to run mysql on the same network as well. Also, an important point to note that there were capacity issues on the server, a server restart seemed to fix the issue and I could get it running standalone without the network as well (but ofcourse in this case the app could not connect to it).